# What is included in a Themeforest template

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to punch up my UI with an HTML/CSS template.  I'm using AngularJS with Bootstrap and I have a number of custom functions as part of my web/mobile app and I just need some professional looking html/css I can practically copy and past as necessary into my project.

Do Themeforest templates provide access to source code or is it more like SquareSpace where there is no access to the source html/css/js and you'd have to fit your code into their framework?

Comment: Its not asking for a recommendation, its seeking clarification on what a particular resource offers. This is useful because it difficult to separate the reality from bs when sifting through sites such as themeforest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the source code to change as you please.

Source: I have used theme-forest before.